# Is it possible to push text to prompt input?

Tags: node.js, prompt, stdio

I am using the prompt module, node version 12.4.0
I am wondering if its possible to push a string to the 'input field' of a prompt.get()

The following script displays a (double) "prompt: "
After 5 seconds, it inserts the text "This is a test"
When an enter command is given, the string is not recognized as input.
It isn't possible to edit the string before pressing enter either.
(type anything before 5 sec and press enter, and the input WILL display)

End-goal: to have commands send to prompt from external source, but give the end user the ability to modify the commands before entering.

I tried process.stdout.write, process.stdin.write
I also tried to replace process.std*.write with prompt.std*.write
The answer might be os-specific, but I have tried this code both under Win10 x64 as well as Linux

```
const prompt = require("prompt");

function myFunc() {
  process.stdin.write("This is a test");
}
setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);

prompt.get({
  properties: {
    test: {
      description: "prompt"
    }
  }
}, (err, result)=> {
  console.log("input: "+ result.test);
});
```

actual result:
~/Nodejs/temp$ node index.js
prompt: prompt:  This is a test
input:
~/Nodejs/temp$

desired result:
~/Nodejs/temp$ node index.js
prompt: prompt:  This is a test
input: This is a test
~/Nodejs/temp$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into how the prompt module works, I 'solved' this myself.

prompt uses readline behind the curtains, and readline has a .write function that does what I need, send editable text to the prompt.

prompt itself does not extend this function, and since it hasnt been maintained for 3 years, I switched to readline instead.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: 'prompt> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(line);
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
  console.log('Have a great day!');
  process.exit(0);
});


// simulate external input, and write to prompt>
function myFunc() {
  rl.write("This is a test");
}
setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);
```